# How would I access array within JSon object using JayWay JsonPath?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

I am trying to access the values for each of the three Awards object under the 2nd "text" component in the below JSON using Java.  I ultimately want to create objects with the information.

```
{
    "searchApiFormatVersion": "1.0",
    "searchName": "Details for Awards",
    "description": "",
    "totalRowCount": "3",
    "returnedRowCount": "3",
    "startingReturnedRowNumber": "1",
    "basetype": "Project",
    "columnCount": "2",
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "text": "ID",
            "dataType": "string",
            "hierarchy": 1,
            "parentName": "",
            "isEntity": false,
            "isEset": false
        },
        {
            "text": "getPersonnelEffort()",
            "dataType": "method",
            "hierarchy": 2,
            "parentName": "Custom Extension",
            "isEntity": true,
            "isEset": false
        }
    ],
    "resultSet": {
        "rows": [
            {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "text": "A00000029",
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "columnHeader": "ID"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "{\"id\":\"A00000029\",\"allocations\":[{\"AwardID\":\"A00000029\",\"AwardShortTitle\":\"SDH Proposal 001 Grants Capitation2\",\"AwardLongTitle\":\"SDH Proposal 001 Testing2\",\"DirectSponsorName\":\"University of Pennsylvania\",\"DirectSponsorID\":\"UPENN\",\"DirectsponsorAWDID\":\"UP010523\",\"PrimeSponsorName\":null,\"PrimeSponsorID\":null,\"PrimesponsorAWDID\":null,\"CFDA\":null,\"SponsorAwardDate\":null,\"AwardDepartmentID\":\"4011100\",\"AwardDepartmentName\":\"Neurobiology\",\"AwardStartDate\":\"2022-12-01T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardEndDate\":\"2025-11-30T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardProjectState\":\"Active\",\"AwardDateModified\":\"2023-01-10T20:16:01Z\",\"FinancialAccountName\":\"SDH Proposal 001 Grants Capitation2\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitID\":\"4011100\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitName\":\"Neurobiology\",\"FinancialAccountFund\":\"650\",\"FinancialAccountPeopleSoftProjectID\":\"60063974\",\"BudgetAllocationPeriodNumber\":1,\"BudgetAllocationIndirectRate\":60,\"BudgetAllocationStartDate\":\"2022-12-01T06:00:00Z\",\"BudgetAllocationEndDate\":\"2023-11-30T06:00:00Z\",\"Effort\":[]}]}",
                        "dataType": "method",
                        "columnHeader": "getPersonnelEffort()",
                        "oidPath": "com.webridge.entity.Entity[OID[A3B036D38D3B11ED8199285DAF565000]]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "text": "A00000034",
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "columnHeader": "ID"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "{\"id\":\"A00000034\",\"allocations\":[{\"AwardID\":\"A00000034\",\"AwardShortTitle\":\"LC Test 01/04/23 - Non-Fed\",\"AwardLongTitle\":\"LC Test 01/04/2023 - Non-Fed\",\"DirectSponsorName\":\"23andMe, Inc.\",\"DirectSponsorID\":\"23ANDME\",\"DirectsponsorAWDID\":\"1234\",\"PrimeSponsorName\":null,\"PrimeSponsorID\":null,\"PrimesponsorAWDID\":null,\"CFDA\":null,\"SponsorAwardDate\":null,\"AwardDepartmentID\":\"5111200\",\"AwardDepartmentName\":\"Behavioral Medicine\",\"AwardStartDate\":\"2023-01-01T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardEndDate\":\"2026-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardProjectState\":\"Active\",\"AwardDateModified\":\"2023-01-10T16:16:40Z\",\"FinancialAccountName\":\"LC Test 01/04/23 - Non-Fed\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitID\":\"5111200\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitName\":\"Behavioral Medicine\",\"FinancialAccountFund\":\"610\",\"FinancialAccountPeopleSoftProjectID\":null,\"BudgetAllocationPeriodNumber\":1,\"BudgetAllocationIndirectRate\":70.54679870605469,\"BudgetAllocationStartDate\":\"2023-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"BudgetAllocationEndDate\":\"2024-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"Effort\":[{\"AcademicMonthsEffort\":2,\"AcademicMonthsSalaryRequested\":1,\"CalendarMonthsRequested\":1,\"CalendarMonthsEffort\":2,\"CalendarCostShareMonths\":1,\"CalendarCostShareSalaryRequestedPercent\":0.07999999821186065,\"CalendarEffortPercent\":0.17000000178813934,\"SummerMonthsEffort\":null,\"SummerMonthsSalaryRequested\":null,\"DistributeEffort\":false,\"PersonnelRole\":\"PD/PI\",\"PersonFirstName\":\"Leah\",\"PersonLastName\":\"Aberman\",\"PersonEmployeeID\":\"3247211\",\"PersonAppointmentType\":12,\"PersonStartDate\":\"2023-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"PersonEndDate\":\"2024-01-31T06:00:00Z\"}]},{\"AwardID\":\"A00000034\",\"AwardShortTitle\":\"LC Test 01/04/23 - Non-Fed\",\"AwardLongTitle\":\"LC Test 01/04/2023 - Non-Fed\",\"DirectSponsorName\":\"23andMe, Inc.\",\"DirectSponsorID\":\"23ANDME\",\"DirectsponsorAWDID\":\"1234\",\"PrimeSponsorName\":null,\"PrimeSponsorID\":null,\"PrimesponsorAWDID\":null,\"CFDA\":null,\"SponsorAwardDate\":null,\"AwardDepartmentID\":\"5111200\",\"AwardDepartmentName\":\"Behavioral Medicine\",\"AwardStartDate\":\"2023-01-01T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardEndDate\":\"2026-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardProjectState\":\"Active\",\"AwardDateModified\":\"2023-01-10T16:16:40Z\",\"FinancialAccountName\":\"LC Test 01/04/23 - Non-Fed\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitID\":\"5111200\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitName\":\"Behavioral Medicine\",\"FinancialAccountFund\":\"610\",\"FinancialAccountPeopleSoftProjectID\":null,\"BudgetAllocationPeriodNumber\":3,\"BudgetAllocationIndirectRate\":72,\"BudgetAllocationStartDate\":\"2025-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"BudgetAllocationEndDate\":\"2026-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"Effort\":[{\"AcademicMonthsEffort\":12,\"AcademicMonthsSalaryRequested\":11,\"CalendarMonthsRequested\":11,\"CalendarMonthsEffort\":12,\"CalendarCostShareMonths\":1,\"CalendarCostShareSalaryRequestedPercent\":0.07999999821186065,\"CalendarEffortPercent\":1,\"SummerMonthsEffort\":null,\"SummerMonthsSalaryRequested\":null,\"DistributeEffort\":false,\"PersonnelRole\":\"PD/PI\",\"PersonFirstName\":\"Leah\",\"PersonLastName\":\"Aberman\",\"PersonEmployeeID\":\"3247211\",\"PersonAppointmentType\":12,\"PersonStartDate\":\"2025-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"PersonEndDate\":\"2026-01-31T06:00:00Z\"}]}]}",
                        "dataType": "method",
                        "columnHeader": "getPersonnelEffort()",
                        "oidPath": "com.webridge.entity.Entity[OID[E0E466FA8DEA11ED8199285DAF565000]]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "text": "A00000040",
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "columnHeader": "ID"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "{\"id\":\"A00000040\",\"allocations\":[{\"AwardID\":\"A00000040\",\"AwardShortTitle\":\"KSA0109 DOD CS\",\"AwardLongTitle\":\"KSA0109 DOD CS long title\",\"DirectSponsorName\":\"Air Force Office of Scientific Research\",\"DirectSponsorID\":\"AFOSR\",\"DirectsponsorAWDID\":\"AFOSR0109ABC\",\"PrimeSponsorName\":null,\"PrimeSponsorID\":null,\"PrimesponsorAWDID\":null,\"CFDA\":\"12.431\",\"SponsorAwardDate\":null,\"AwardDepartmentID\":\"40115001\",\"AwardDepartmentName\":\"Physics & Astronomy\",\"AwardStartDate\":\"2023-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardEndDate\":\"2026-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardProjectState\":\"Active\",\"AwardDateModified\":\"2023-01-10T21:59:43Z\",\"FinancialAccountName\":\"KSA01091 DOD CS\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitID\":\"40115001\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitName\":\"Physics & Astronomy\",\"FinancialAccountFund\":\"610\",\"FinancialAccountPeopleSoftProjectID\":\"60063981\",\"BudgetAllocationPeriodNumber\":1,\"BudgetAllocationIndirectRate\":0,\"BudgetAllocationStartDate\":\"2023-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"BudgetAllocationEndDate\":\"2024-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"Effort\":[]},{\"AwardID\":\"A00000040\",\"AwardShortTitle\":\"KSA0109 DOD CS\",\"AwardLongTitle\":\"KSA0109 DOD CS long title\",\"DirectSponsorName\":\"Air Force Office of Scientific Research\",\"DirectSponsorID\":\"AFOSR\",\"DirectsponsorAWDID\":\"AFOSR0109A\",\"PrimeSponsorName\":null,\"PrimeSponsorID\":null,\"PrimesponsorAWDID\":null,\"CFDA\":\"12.431\",\"SponsorAwardDate\":null,\"AwardDepartmentID\":\"4011500\",\"AwardDepartmentName\":\"Physics & Astronomy\",\"AwardStartDate\":\"2023-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardEndDate\":\"2026-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"AwardProjectState\":\"Active\",\"AwardDateModified\":\"2023-01-10T21:59:43Z\",\"FinancialAccountName\":\"KSA0109 DOD CS\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitID\":\"4011500\",\"FinancialAccountResponsibleUnitName\":\"Physics & Astronomy\",\"FinancialAccountFund\":\"610\",\"FinancialAccountPeopleSoftProjectID\":\"60063981\",\"BudgetAllocationPeriodNumber\":1,\"BudgetAllocationIndirectRate\":60,\"BudgetAllocationStartDate\":\"2023-02-01T06:00:00Z\",\"BudgetAllocationEndDate\":\"2024-01-31T06:00:00Z\",\"Effort\":[]}]}",
                        "dataType": "method",
                        "columnHeader": "getPersonnelEffort()",
                        "oidPath": "com.webridge.entity.Entity[OID[A07BF574903C11ED8199285DAF565000]]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using Jayway JsonPath syntax to access it and can get down to the text component using the code below.

```
        String jsonPath = "$." + "resultSet" + "." + "rows" + ".." + "text";
        String response = JsonPath.read(stringJsonResponse, jsonPath).toString();
        logger.info("Response: " + response);
```

When I try something like the below, I get an empty response.  Would anyone know how to dig down deeper?

String jsonPath = "$." + "resultSet" + "." + "rows" + ".." + "text" + ".." + "AwardID;

Comment: `resultSet.rows.text` is a String representation of a JSON object.  You need to de-serialize the string first for further JSON query.  Library [Josson](https://github.com/octomix/josson) can do that in one step.

Comment: I ended up switching to JackSon to do this, and it was much easier.